# Unable add element to top of hashset

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset

I was using arraylist to populate an optionscollection in jsp. Now i dont need duplicate elements.So i want to use hashset. If i use hashset , unlike arraylist if i want to display a blank if i add a blank as the first element and then add other data the blank is displaying at the end of the combobox. When i use arraylist if i add blank as the first element it displays at the start which is what i need.

Can any one help me to add the blank at the beginning for hashset ?

Comment: A HashSet _does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time_. Please read the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`HashSet` is not an ordered version of a `Set`. Use `LinkedHashSet` when you need an ordered `Set` and `TreeSet` when you need a sorted one.

Answer (score 4):

As noted, HashSets aren't ordered. You either need:

1. a sorted variant ([LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) orders based upon *insertion order*, or [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) which orders according to the elements' *natural ordering*)
2. to sort on iteration based upon criteria particular to that use case